# I want Spring not to create tables for some of my entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, entity, multi-tenant

I currently have a multi-tenant application with a "main" database. On the other hand, I have a few entities that correspond to tables that belong to other databases.

I need to have these other entities and their repositories to be able to retrieve data from the other databases, but when I launch the application Spring will create a new table in my "main" database for each of those entities.

Is it possible to tell spring not to create such tables?

(I thought of setting spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update to "none", but I'd like to keep this property as it is right now)

Comment: I'd generally caution against having Hibernate automatically execute DDL operations like creating tables - especially in production environments. You don't want some error in the code to mess up your database or drop entire tables. Instead go for separate and controlled updates, maybe even using some tool like Flyway or Liquibase.

Comment: I would recommend that you use `Flyway`  so that you can keep more control on what changes to a database happens over time and also get a history in no time